# MATLAB sorting data and creating matrix by year

Tags: matlab, loops, date-sorting

I have the following data sample:

```
2001    1
2000    1
1974    1
2007    1
2007    2
2007    6
2007    3
1994    1
1986    1
2007    1
```

I want to sort the data by year and then plot the values. I wrote a code using `for` and `find`. However, using `fprintf` I got only the output in the command window, like this:

```
Ano-modelo 2009 | 88242 veiculos 
Ano-modelo 2010 | 125822 veiculos 
Ano-modelo 2011 | 132360 veiculos 
Ano-modelo 2012 | 167984 veiculos
```

So, Is there some alternative way that, inside `for` loop, to create a matrix c = [year; sum_vehicles]?

My code is the following:

```
dados = dlmread('c:\experimental\frota_detran\frota-detran_total.dat');

ano = 1922:2015;

for i = ano

%procura somente os valores a cada ano
pro = find(dados(:,1)==i);
%lista somente os valores
qt = dados(pro,:);
%soma o ano modelo em questao
total = sum (qt(:,2));


%exibe os valores para cada ano modelo
fprintf('%s %d %s %d %s \n','Ano-modelo',i ,'|',total, 'veiculos');

end
```

Comment: I'm curious what else you thought `fprintf` would do besides printing. What format do you want `c` to be? It looks like `dados` is already in that format.

Comment: @Suever In fact, the data input (`frota-detran_total.dat`) is disorganized. My intention is to group and to sort the quantity values by year. `fptintf`is just for visualization on command window.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want the data sorted and aggregated:

```
[sorted ia ic] = unique(dados(:,1));
c = [sorted accumarray(ic, dados(:,2))];
```

Comment: Precisely! I didn't express myself properly.